# How to run parallel test suites in TestNG

Tags: selenium, testng

I am try to run parallel test suites using below command.

```
java -cp testng-6.3.1.jar;test.jar;selenium-server-standalone-2.18.0.jar org.testng.TestNG -suitethreadpoolsize 2 testng-vm1.xml testng-vm2.xml
```

When i execute above command, the last testng xml file only (i.e testng-vm2.xml) is running.  But i want to run both xml files parallel .

As i know that the above command is getting from http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-tests

Please let me know is it possible to run parallel suites through TestNG?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a better solution by creating a Maven Project and configuring it to run your tests in parallel.

More details:
Starting with Maven
http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

TestNG (and its parallel config)
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html